# How to pass a random number from one class to another class?

Tags: android

I'm making Sudoku game. There are two classes: difficulty and Screen class. When the 'easy' button is pressed, I want to generate a random number from 1 to 9, and that numbers should go to the Screen class layout.

My 'easy' button is in `choosedifficulty` class layout.

Comment: Get the book 'Hello Android', it builds a sudoku (which you can reuse) and explains how to do what you mentioned (it even adds background music!) :D

Comment: What type of a class is the Screen class? Is it an activity? Do you want to launch it when the button gets pressed? You should probably show us the code related to the question.

Comment: yes Screen class is an activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be carefull cause a sudoku is not only "random numbers from 1 to 9", so I recommend you to implement the algorithm properly. (Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_algorithms).

About passing data from one activity to another, you can use the intent. For example:

```
//In the place you launch your game
Intent myIntent = new Intent(myContext, Screen.class);
//sudoku is a String, for example, that contains the sudoku you want to pass
myIntent.putExtra("sudokukey", sudoku);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

And then, to retrieve the data:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String mySudoku = bundle.getString("sudokukey");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass information between activities using Intent extras. In your case, you could do (assuming I understood what you wanna do):

```
  public void startSudoku(int chosenDifficulty) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,   // Your current activity
        SudokuActivity.class);    // The activity showing the Sudoku
    i.addExtra("com.example.sudoku.DifficultyLevel", chosenDifficulty);
    startActivity(i);
  }
```

Then, in the onCreate method of your Sudoku activity, you can get the difficulty level:

```
private int difficulty = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        difficulty = extras.getInt("com.example.sudoku.DifficultyLevel", 0);
    }
}
```